# Kolmogorov-Smirnov test: why does the critical value increase when $\alpha$ decreases?

Tags: statistics

When performing a Kolmogorov-Smirnov test, we compute the [KS distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test#Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_statistic) between the empirical cumulative distribution function, and the theoretical one. Then, we compare this measure with the corresponding [critical value](http://oak.ucc.nau.edu/rh83/Statistics/ks1/), and reject the null hypothesis (the sample is drawn from the reference distribution) if the distance is larger than the critical value.

But if we look at the table of [critical values](http://oak.ucc.nau.edu/rh83/Statistics/ks1/), we can see that they increase as $\alpha$ gets smaller. My understanding was that $\alpha$ was the risk of making an error, so I would expect that the higher $\alpha$ is, the higher the risk, and so the higher the critical value should be.

**Why does the critical value increase when $\alpha$ decreases?**

Answer (score 1):

The level of significance α is supposed to the probability at which the null hypothesis $H_0$ can be rejected. But when checking the statistical tables for $t_\alpha$, $z_\alpha$, and $χ^2_\alpha$, the values increase with decrease in $\alpha$ leading to the conception that the acceptance region increases as the strictness increases.

Comment: Yes - though I might have said this as: $\alpha$ is the probability under the null hypothesis of being beyond the critical value, so a larger magnitude for the critical value corresponds to a smaller probability $\alpha$ of an observation being beyond it.

Comment: @Henry I am confused. If I am testing wheter my sample is drawn from a given reference distribution with $\alpha = 0.1$, can I say that roughly speaking, there is a $10 \%$ chance that my test is not reliable ?

Comment: Not quite: you can say that if your sample is indeed drawn from that distribution then there would be a $10\%$ chance your observation is in the rejection region (beyond the $\alpha=0.1$ critical value) but you cannot without more analysis say anything about what happens if your sample is drawn from a different distribution